# How to use use derived table column in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one table mytrade like following

```
tradeid securityid quantity

111    899    12000
112    899    1000
113    788    15000
114    566    -15000
115    566    -1000
```

so to gather total quantity for security id i write following query (I tried this into #temptable also create temptable and then select below )

```
select
tradeid,
securityid,
sum(quantity) OVER(Partition by securityid) as total
from mytrade
```

which gives me output like below

```
tradeid securityid total

114    566    -16000
115    566    -16000
113    788    15000
111    899    13000
112    899    13000
```

now i want to insert values into secondtable based on "total" quantity.

```
insert secondTable (securityid,quantity,price)
(
select securityid,quantity,101.1 from mydata..mytrade
where #temptable.total = 13000 and securityid = 899
)
```

but getting error:

The multi-part identifier "#temptable.total" could not be bound.

if i put this whole statement into#temptable and then assign as above then also getting this error how should i bound "total" column please guide me?

Comment: Where are you referencing the #tempTable in the from clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT secondTable (securityid,quantity,price)
(
SELECT securityid,quantity,101.1 FROM (
  SELECT
tradeid,
securityid,
sum(quantity) OVER(Partition BY securityid) AS total,
quantity
FROM mytrade)T
WHERE total = 13000 AND securityid = 899
)
```

You can find a full working solution on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9cab/12).

Answer (score 0):

```
select securityid,quantity,101.1 from #temptable
where #temptable.total = 13000 and securityid = 899
```